# Binding MediaElement source from button content (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, button, mediaelement

I have a problem with `Button` control. I've made `Button` in `Shape` of circle and `MediaElement` inside it. Thats's my code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Templ" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid Margin="5">
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF6DB4EF"/>

            <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#00000000"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.88" Color="#00000000"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#80000000"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse Margin="10">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush>
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <MediaElement Source="{???}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>    
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

My problem is that I cant bind `MediaElement` Source from main `XAML`:

```
<Button Template="{DynamicResource Templ}" Content="D:\dykta.avi"/>
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `MediaElement.Source` property from the button's `Content` property, you can simply bind to it:

```
<MediaElement Source="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
              Stretch="Fill"/>
```